How can I use "accelerate launch" in my anaconda virtual environment?
I have installed accelerate by using the following command in my own anaconda environment:
pip install accelerate
But when I try to locate the path of accelerate, it appears like:
$ which accelerate /home/user/.local/bin/accelerate
I also try to use accelerate to train a model by using the following command, after activate my anaconda env:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 accelerate launch \ --mixed_precision bf16 \ --num_machines 1 \ --num_cpu_threads_per_process 2 \ --num_processes $NUM_GPUS \ --use_deepspeed \ --deepspeed_config_file stage3_no_offloading_accelerate.conf \ finetune.py \ --model_name_or_path  ../../Llama-2-7b-hf \ --use_flash_attn \ --tokenizer_name ../../Llama-2-7b-hf \ --use_slow_tokenizer \ --train_file full_output_1005.jsonl \ --max_seq_length 2048 \ --preprocessing_num_workers 16 \ --per_device_train_batch_size $BATCH_SIZE_PER_GPU \ --gradient_accumulation_steps $GRADIENT_ACC_STEPS \ --learning_rate 2e-5 \ --lr_scheduler_type linear \ --warmup_ratio 0.03 \ --weight_decay 0. \ --num_train_epochs 3 \ --output_dir output/self_rag_${MODEL_SIZE}/ \ --with_tracking \ --report_to tensorboard \ --logging_steps 1 \ --use_special_tokens
Similar bug appeared:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user/.local/bin/accelerate", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/accelerate_cli.py", line 47, in main args.func(args) File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 995, in launch_command args, defaults, mp_from_config_flag = _validate_launch_command(args) File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 928, in _validate_launch_command raise ValueError(err.format(mode="bf16", requirement="PyTorch >= 1.10 and a supported device.")) ValueError: bf16 mixed precision requires PyTorch >= 1.10 and a supported device.
In fact, I have install torch in my anaconda env, but it seems that "accelerate launch" didn't use my virtual env. I wonder how to fix this problem.
In fact, I have install torch in my anaconda env, but it seems that "accelerate launch" didn't use my virtual env. I wonder how to fix this problem.
